# Bounded operators on inner products on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If we have a Hilbert space $H$ with inner product $( \cdot | \cdot)$, and let $( \cdot| \cdot)_1 $ be another inner product on $H$ such that $(x | x)_1 \leq (x | x)$ for every $x \in H$. I was trying to show that  there is an injective, positive operator $ T \in B(H)$, with $0 \leq T\leq I$, such that $(Tx | y) = (x | y)_1$ for all $ x,y \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x\in H $. Then $ y\longmapsto (x|y)_1$ is a linear functional. It is bounded, because
$$
|\, (x|y)_1\,|\leq (x|x)_1^{1/2}\, (y|y)_1^{1/2}\leq (x|x)_1^{1/2}\, (y|y)^{1/2}.
$$
By the Riesz  representation theorem, there exists  $x'\in H $ such that $$ (x|y)_1=(x'|y). $$ Now one shows that $x'$ is unique, so $x\longmapsto Tx=x'$ is well defined. The uniqueness also implies that $T $ is linear. Injectivity, and positivity of $T $ now follow easily.

To see that  $T $ is a contraction, 
$$
\|Tx\|^2=(x'|x')=(x|x')_1\leq (x|x)_1^{1/2}(x'|x')_1^{1/2}
\leq (x|x)^{1/2}(x'|x')^{1/2}=\|x\|\,\|Tx\|.
$$ If $Tx\ne0$, we get $\|Tx\|\leq\|x\|$.

Comment: How can we show uniqueness of T?

Comment: If $(T_1x|y)=(T_2x|y) $ for all $x,y $, then $T_1=T_2$.

Comment: Why did you show T is contraction?

Comment: Because it was a requirement of the question. You wanted $0\leq T\leq I$.